# Is there a way of assigning properties through a hierarchy of classes?

Tags: c#, overriding

Please see the following hierarchy of classes:

```
Person [age, country, hair color, eyes color..]
   Adult [job, car..]
      Man [favorite beer..]
      Woman [purse..]
   Child [school, favorite toy]
      Boy
      Girl [doll]
```

Each of those derived classes has specific properties: for example, an adult may have a job but a child does not. A girl may have a favorite doll and a school's name. A boy does have a school name too but he hasn't any favorite doll.

I want to implement a method that clones a `Boy` (retuns a `Boy` object with exact same properties). Instead of returning a `Boy` and manually setting all properties inherited from `Child` and `Person` I'd like to avoid that.

Note: `Child`, `Adult` and `Person` are abstract classes.

Note2: All these folks has complicated references that I don't want to copy, in some cases I just want to copy the ID of that references, but that should be done manually, so I need some control of the cloned objects.

I've thought of an virtual method in `Person` that is overridden in each subclass, but as `Person` cannot be instantiated I'm not sure how to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Implement [`ICloneable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) on them, that way your derived classes can also implement it as well and you only have to call Clone on the base class to get the derived class.

Comment: Would I be able to select what properties I want to clone? Some of them, like personal ID number should be different

Comment: *"The ICloneable interface enables you to provide a customized implementation that creates a copy of an existing object."* Yes, you can pick and choose what you want to clone in the `Clone` method you override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going down the path shallow/deep cloning (as Marco points out), you can achieve this, using your own `Clone` function.

```
class Person
{
   public Person(Person rhs) // cctor
   {
       Age = rhs.Age;
   }

   public int Age { get; set; }

   public abstract Person Clone();
}


   public class Adult : Person
   {
       public Adult(Adult rhs) : base(rhs)
       {
           JobType = rhs.JobType;
       }

       public JobType Job { get; set; }

       public override Person Clone() { return new Adult(this); }
   }
```

Comment: How would be this be done if several abstract classes are between the base class and the actual class object I want to clone? (`Adult` is abstract too).

Comment: @Sturm, you just need to call the copy constructor and implement `Clone` at each class level.

Comment: Still can't get it since I cannot call the constructor of the abstract class! So can't pass that level in my hierarchy!

Comment: The thing is that you don't need to override `Clone` in abstract classes. I choose this answer due its simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Take 3 ...

Solution 1:

My prefered way is to use ICopyTo. I think it is preferable than anything else because it forces to have an object of proper type to copy to. It also does cloning and copy at the same time. Easier to maintain.

Also using the interface help doing the right thing. Don't forget to call base.CopyTo ...

Also, we can say that CopyTo is part of [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

```
public interface ICopyTo<T>
{
    T CopyTo(T target);
}

public abstract class Person : ICopyTo<Person>, ICloneable
{
    public Person CopyTo(Person person)
    {
        person.Age = Age;
        person.Country = Country;
        return person;
    }

    public abstract object Clone();

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Adult : Person, ICopyTo<Adult>, ICloneable
{
    public Adult CopyTo(Adult adult)
    {
        base.CopyTo(this);
        adult.Car = Car;
        return adult;
    }

    public string Car { get; set; }
}

public class Man : Adult, ICopyTo<Man>,  ICloneable
{
    public Man CopyTo(Man man = null)
    {
        if (man == null)
        {
            man = new Man();
        }
        base.CopyTo(this);
        man.Beer = Beer;

        return man;
    }


    public string Beer { get; set; }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        return CopyTo();
    }
}

public class Woman : Adult, ICopyTo<Woman>, ICloneable
{
    public Woman CopyTo(Woman woman = null)
    {
        if (woman == null)
        {
            woman = new Woman();
        }
        base.CopyTo(this);
        woman.Purse = Purse;
        return woman;
    }

    public string Purse { get; set; }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        return CopyTo();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Go()
    {
        Man man1 = new Man() {Age = 10, Beer = "Bud", Country = "Canada"};
        Man man2 = new Man();
        man1.CopyTo(man2); // Real copy

        Woman woman1 = new Woman() {Age = 32, Country = "USA", Purse = "Anything"};
        Woman woman2 = woman1.CopyTo(); // Cloning

        List<Person> adults = new List<Person>();
        adults.Add(man1);
        adults.Add(man2);
        adults.Add(woman2);

        Person person0 = adults[0].Clone() as Person;
        Person person1 = adults[1].Clone() as Person;
        Person person2 = adults[2].Clone() as Person;
    }
}
```

Solution 2: (Close to solution 1  but with ICloneable only at base class)

```
public interface ICopyTo<T>
{
    T CopyTo(T target);
}

public abstract class Person : ICopyTo<Person>, ICloneable
{
    public virtual Person CopyTo(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("person can't be null");
        }

        person.Age = Age;
        person.Country = Country;
        return person;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return CopyTo(null);
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Adult : Person, ICopyTo<Adult>, ICloneable
{
    public Adult CopyTo(Adult adult)
    {
        if (adult == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("adult can't be null");
        }

        base.CopyTo(this);
        adult.Car = Car;
        return adult;
    }

    public override Person CopyTo(Person person)
    {
        return CopyTo(person as Adult);
    }

    public string Car { get; set; }
}

public class Man : Adult, ICopyTo<Man>
{
    public Man CopyTo(Man man = null)
    {
        if (man == null)
        {
            man = new Man();
        }
        base.CopyTo(this);
        man.Beer = Beer;

        return man;
    }

    public override Person CopyTo(Person person)
    {
        return CopyTo(person as Man);
    }

    public string Beer { get; set; }
}

public class Woman : Adult, ICopyTo<Woman>
{
    public Woman CopyTo(Woman woman = null)
    {
        if (woman == null)
        {
            woman = new Woman();
        }
        base.CopyTo(this);
        woman.Purse = Purse;
        return woman;
    }

    public override Person CopyTo(Person person)
    {
        return CopyTo(person as Woman);
    }

    public string Purse { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Go()
    {
        Man man1 = new Man() {Age = 10, Beer = "Bud", Country = "Canada"};
        Man man2 = new Man();
        man1.CopyTo(man2); // Real copy

        Woman woman1 = new Woman() {Age = 32, Country = "USA", Purse = "Anything"};
        Woman woman2 = woman1.CopyTo(); // Cloning

        List<Person> adults = new List<Person>();
        adults.Add(man1);
        adults.Add(man2);
        adults.Add(woman2);

        Person person0 = adults[0].Clone() as Person;
        Person person1 = adults[1].Clone() as Person;
        Person person2 = adults[2].Clone() as Person;
    }
}
```

Solution 3:

```
public static T Clone<T>(T source)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
    }

    // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (stream)
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Outstanding examples. It's very nice to see so many approaches to the same problem. This is the one (1) preferred by me as well :)

Comment: In your updated answer, ICloneable interface is used now. And it's inherited by each subclass even if the base class already implements that interface. Why is that?

Comment: I agree it's sounds unnecessary... i'm looking to see if I can do use only an implementation on the base. I come back in few minutes...

Comment: By the way, it seems that in your country 'adults' can drink beer since the young age of 10 :)

Comment: I just bring some more corrections... I can't override if parameters are not the same. I had little mistakes with "virtual ... CopyTo", I can't make it virtual (I means there is no reason to do so) because I can't override in subclasses. I think it is ok as it is right now. But I can't say it is the best way to do it... I'm curious to see if there is better ways ? I think that to benefits from inheritance, the type of object passed as parameter to ICopyTo has to be the most top base class and cast. But doing so will prevent copy to be type safe. I will continue to monitor this to see better...

Comment: I did a solution 2, perhaps you prefer this one ;-) !

Answer (score 0):

The `MemberwiseClone()` method may be what you're looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx

Be advised you'll need to clone any members of the class that are reference types manually as the above function will only clone their references and the resulting Boy clone's members will refer to the same instance as the original for those members.

If most or all of your members are reference types ICloneable is a more robust solution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple the on the base class, you can use virtual so if you want to  override in upper classes.

```
public abstract class Person : ICloneable {
             public virtual object Clone() {
              //all upper classes is a Person object
              person = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType());
                    person.job = this.job; 
                    // ect more properties Lazy or Deep clone
                    person.blah = this.blah;
                    return person;
                }
           }

public abstract class Adult : Person {
      override object Clone() {
                    Adult adult =  (Adult) base.Clone();
                    adult.job = this.job;
                }
          }
```

Comment: While I agree with the use of the interface, I don't think you should use the `Activator.CreateInstance`, its creating a new object, not cloning.

Comment: First of all when we clone a object must create the same instance of the same object. Then on the upper classes that's we is virtual you make the code, for deep clone or lazy clone.

Comment: I understand that, but you have it marked `virtual` not `abstract` which means the derived classes have the *option* to implement it or not, those that do not, simply return a new instance of the class, not a clone, even though the `Clone` method exists, its very confusing. If you want to make sure that derived classes implement it, mark it `abstract`, not `virtual` (but then you can't have a method body).

Comment: Must have an implementation of code this was a sample not the full code. public virtual object Clone() {
                    Person person = Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType());              person.job = this.job; // ect more properties 
return person;}

Comment: Is there an alternative to `Activator.CreateInstance`?

Comment: Is this example Activator.CreateInstance it's very helpful because whatever type is the upper classes or any type it will create the inistance of the current object. If you don't want to use Activator.CreateInstance with type then you have to implement for each class specific clone method.